Should we remove links from tag excerpts?
There are some tags whose excerpts include a link, for example lightning-development-kit:

Lightning Development Kit (LDK) is a library written in Rust that
allows you to build a lightning node without worrying about
implementing low-level lightning logic correctly. More details here:
https://github.com/lightningdevkit

One problem is that this link is not clickable either in the tag tooltip or the tag info page, you actually need to copy and paste it. And I don't think it even makes sense conceptually to have links in tag excerpts. I propose we establish this as a general guideline and move current offending links to the full tag wiki.

That's a good idea!
